# dual boot truble

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, windows-7

I am having trouble setting up a dual boot. I can make ubuntu work, or I can make windows work I can't get them to dule boot. I had windows installed on a new computer, partitioned the drive and installed ubuntu. partitioning the drive crashed windows, so I did a recovery. windows bootloader took over grub and I couldn't figure out how to configure it so I took the easy rout and reinstalled ubuntu which seems to have crashed windows again. I really want linux to work but since I can't get wine to work at all I need windows. I'm about to just write it off as a bad idea and stick to windows. apperenty I'm not clever enough to make it work.

Comment: "Crashed Windows"? This wont happen unless ubuntu is modifying the windows partition(Which it doesent do be default)

Answer (score 1):

I think that You may do something wrong during installation process, so please describe what exactly are You doing and what options are You using. However, I think that the best way is to use virtualization. For example I use Virtual Box, and thanks to this I have two systems running at the same time on one PC. I also have used dual boot, but virtualization is so much better, easier and more comfortable.